# Complex logic which produces true/false to control visibility

Tags: qt, qml, qlistview

I have the following QML code:

```
ListView {
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            eleText: "Me"
            eleFirst: true
            eleSecond: true
        }
        ListElement {
            eleText: "My GF"
            eleFirst: false
            eleSecond: false                         
        }
        ListElement {
            eleText: "Ben Dover"
            eleFirst: true
            eleSecond: false
        }
    }
    delegate: Row {
        visible: true
        Label: eleText
    }
}
```

I intend to have a complex logic to control the `visibility` of each row on my `ListView`. I mean, to set the `visible:` field, I like to have this complex logic:

```
if( someObject.getStatus() == "first" ) {
    if (eleFirst) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
} else if ( someObject.getStatus() == "second" ) {
    if (eleSecond) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    // Should not get here
    // throw errors
}
```

How can I use such a complex logic to control the `visibility` of my `ListView` rows?

---

I have to use Qt 5.9.4

Comment: and if getStatus() is neither first nor second, should it be visible or not?

Comment: You could implement this logic in a `QSortFilterProxyModel` in C++, then expose the class to QML and use it as filter between your actual model and the view

Comment: what does `Label: eleText` mean? why not implement the login in the model? Add some property, let's say `eleVisible` and so set it whenever you need. It is not so clear from the code what is `logic`, please provide the full code.

Comment: @folibis The problem is that the visibility of each element is dependent upon `someObject.getStatus()`. As far as I checked the model can only have basic types, so I thought I cannot implement logic in the model.

Comment: Are trying to do like if status changed then the visibility of Label also change?

Comment: from the Qt docs: _Beginning with Qt 5.11 ListElement also allows assigning a function declaration to a role._

Comment: @folibis Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using Qt 5.9.4

Comment: @Jiu Yes, if some status changes, then the items of `ListView` get visible or non-visible depending on that status

Comment: umm...maybe change 'complex logic' part help understands the question.

Comment: How did you bind & map the ListElement with someObject?

Comment: @Jiu By a combination of `Q_PROPERTY` and `Q_INVOKABLE` and `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`

Comment: If you want a complex model, subclass the [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html). There you can define your own role for visibility and whatever logic you need. Alternatively shorten your logic to a ternary operator.

Comment: @folibis You forgot the second part of the paragraph: "This allows the definition of ListElements with callable actions.". So it is merely to store a function as a role data, not a way to define a role data with a function.

Comment: @JanWin I believe your comment solves my problem. Can you post your comment as an answer so that this question can be closed as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a complex model, subclass the [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html). There you can define your own role for visibility and whatever logic you need. Alternatively shorten your logic to a ternary operator.